# ng-repeat of json in value of another ng-reapeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an ng-repeat that iterates through a JSON and renderes a table. What I want to do is to iterate through the value that is a JSON itself. But It behaves like a string.

```
<tr
    ng-repeat="(key,value) in event.kibana._source track by $index"
    ng-class-odd="'odd'">
        <td>{{key}}</td>
        <td>
            <span>{{value}}</span>
            <span ng-repeat="(k,val) in value track by $index">{{k}}|{{val}} </span>
        </td>
</tr>
```

"value" is a JSON. The result inside the td looks like this:

> {"bezeichnung":"Basis","name":"Basis","id":16} 0|{ 1|" 2|b 3|e 4|z 5|e
>   6|i 7|c 8|h 9|n 10|u 11|n 12|g 13|" 14|: 15|" 16|B 17|a 18|s 19|i 20|s
>   21|" 22|, 23|" 24|n 25|a 26|m 27|e 28|" 29|: 30|" 31|B 32|a 33|s 34|i
>   35|s 36|" 37|, 38|" 39|i 40|d 41|" 42|: 43|1 44|6 45|}

Of course this is not what I want. i want to iterate through the JSON and not the string. How can I do that?

EDIT:

THIS is what the JSON looks like:

```
{
    "fold":11,
    "id":64894760,
    "entities":[{"bezeichnung":"Basis","name":"Basis","id":16}]
}
```

Comment: you should also post your actual json data.

Comment: Ypu have nested ng-repeat. So you need to also post the first ng-repeat data.

Comment: What do you mean @Ved?

Comment: I am sayin g that, you have nested ng-repeat. So please post your parent ng-repeat data also.

Comment: The variable "event.kibana._source" is the JSON. I am not sure how the higher levels of the JSON would be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse JSON.(ex. JSON.parse(yourString)) https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: How to use it inside the ng-repeat? "(k,val) in JSON.parse(value) track by $index" doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

try removing `track by $index`. read the documentation here: [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

```
<tr id="{{key}}"
    ng-repeat="(key,value) in event.kibana._source"
    ng-class-odd="'odd'">
        <td>{{key}}</td>
        <td>
            <span>{{value}}</span>  //array of objects, [{"bezeichnung":"Basis","name":"Basis","id":16}]
            <div ng-repeat="val in value track by val.id">  //single value in 'value' array
                <span ng-repeat="(k,v) in val track by k">{{k}}|{{v}} </span>
            </div>
        </td>
</tr>
```

Problem was "value" was an array of object and you had "basis" as value for two keys. So, if tracked using key in the object, AngularJS can differentiate.
I've consider "id" key is unique for a particular value.

Comment: Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: (k,val) in value

Comment: @NikoLang JSON is this variable, event.kibana._source?

Comment: yes "event.kibana._source" is the JSON I posted above

Comment: Your answer looks comprehensible but I get the error "Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: val in value track by val.id, Duplicate key: undefined" and I dont know why.